# Does ASINetworkQueue support multiple requestDidFinishSelectors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, selector, network-protocols

In a view controller, I have multiple methods with different ASIFormDataRequests which have different finishSelectors.  so methodA -> finishselector(AFinished:), methodB ->finishselector(BFinished:), and methodC ->finishselector(CFinished:)

I have a 1 method which handles all requests as shown below:

```
-(void)sendRequest:(NSURL *)url withParams:(NSDictionary *)params andSelector:(NSString *)selector
{
NSString *jsonString = [params yajl_JSONString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:jsonString forKey:@"json"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:15];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:NSSelectorFromString(selector)];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(asiRequestFailed:)];
[[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
[[self networkQueue] go];
}
```

I noticed that when I sent requests for method A->B->C and B finished before A, then BFinished: would be called twice, first with data corresponding to method B, then data corresponding to method A.  Does ASINetworkQueue only handle 1 finishSelector at a time? would i need to separate networkqueues for each method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Requests fired with the ASINetworkQueue still fires their setCompletionBlock on request completion. The completion blocks execute before the queue's selector for requestFinished. See this blog for a tutorial:

http://ygamretuta.me/2011/09/20/manage-multiple-asynchronous-request-in-ios-with-asinetworkqueue/